# How to store bacula (community-edition) backup on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos, backup, bacula

I am using **centOS-7** machine, **bacula community-edition**  11.0.5 and PostgreSql  Database

Bacula is used to take full and incremental backup

I followed bellow document link to store the backup on an Amazon S3 bucket.

https://www.bacula.lat/community/bacula-storage-in-any-cloud-with-rclone-and-rclone-changer/?lang=en

I configured  storage daemon as they shown in the above link, once after the backup, backup is success and backed up file storing in the given path /mnt/vtapes/tapes, but backup-file is not moving from /mnt/vtapes/tapes to  AWS s3 bucket.

In the above document mentioned as, we need to create Schedule routines to the cloud to  move backup file from /mnt/vtapes/tapes to  Amazon S3 bucket.

**I am not aware of  **what is cloud Schedule routines** in AWS, whether it is any cloud lambda function or something else?

**Is there any S3 cloud driver which support bacula backup or any other way to store bacula-community backup file on Amazon S3 other than S3FS-Fuse and libs3 ?**

Comment: Yes. bacula can work with AWS S3.   see https://www.baculasystems.com/blog/amazon-aws-s3-backup/

Answer (score 0):

The link which you shared is for bacula-enterprise, we are using bacula-community. so any related document you prefer for bacula-community  edition

Answer (score 0):

Bacula Community include AWS S3 cloud driver starting from 9.6.0. Check https://www.bacula.org/11.0.x-manuals/en/main/main.pdf - Chapter 3, New Features in 9.6.0. And additional: 4.0.1 New Commands, Resource, and Directives for Cloud. This is the same exact driver available at Enterprise version.